# Initialize CoreData entity only once in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm quite new to using CoreData in Swift and I wanted to create a persistent grade manager for learning purposes.

My class structure is as follows: I have a 'Student' entity in my CoreData with a to-many relationship with a 'Course' entity (with a to-many relationship with a 'Grade' entity).

I want to initialize a student at first startup automatically, so the user only has to add courses and grades, but I can't find out how to do so.

I currently have the initializer in my `viewDidLoad()` but that basically means it gets created a lot of times.

What's the solution to my problem?

Comment: Just check if entity exists in core data then update otherwise add new entity

Comment: If you mean you'll only have one instance of `Student`, ever, then it makes absolutely no sense to put `Student` in Core Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am understanding it correctly, you want only 1 entity of student.
Also putting initialiser code in `viewDidLoad` wont be called multiple times in a single run of the application.

Sure every time you launch the application, a new student will be created.

It has a very basic and easy workaround, which revolves around the concept of fetching and creating.

Follow these steps mentioned in the pseudocode :

```
 methodCreateOfFetchStudent(){
         1. Search Core data for any student entity.
         2. if found then return that studend (there will be only 1 found)
         3. If No student entity is found (array.count == 0) , then create a student with initialisation code.
         4. return that newly created student entity.
  }
```

So for the first time when your application stats, in step 2, no student will be found, and it will create a student and return you the entity.
Afterwards in each run, the method will return the old created student every time.

I hope I understood your requirement and this helped you.